# C regex extraction

Tags: c

Please consider this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char * our_string = "/var/www/html/cameras/cam7/2020-01/15/cam7-2020-01-15-17-45-20-1037-03.h264";
        regex_t re;
        //int regex_int = regcomp(&re, "cam[:digit:]", 0);
        int regex_int = regcomp(&re, "cam", 0);
        if (regex_int) {
                fprintf(stderr, "regex failed to compile!");
                return 1;
        }
        regmatch_t rm[2];
        if ((regexec(&re, our_string, 2, rm,0)) ){
                fprintf(stderr, "regex failed to exec!");
                return 1;
        }
        char temp[8192] = {0};
        memcpy(temp, our_string + rm[1].rm_so, rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so);
        printf("We got: %s\n", temp);
        puts("Bye!");
        return 0;
}
```

I am trying to extract `camX` out of `our_string`, and need help. In its current form, above code is turning blank:

```
$ ./a.out 
We got: 
Bye!
```

C regex is not my forte, Please help!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sIjhjn/1

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not valid POSIX RE syntax.

Comment: Then modify the regex101 page so that it is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That URL doesn't appear to support POSIX regular expressions; there's no option for it in the flavors on the sidebar.

Comment: https://www.regextester.com does support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

```
//int regex_int = regcomp(&re, "cam[:digit:]", 0)
```

If you want to match cam followed by a digit, you need (Besides uncommenting this line, of course, and commenting out the one beneath it), to put `[:digit:]` inside a bracket expression:

```
int regex_int = regcomp(&re, "cam[[:digit:]]", 0)
```

The second issue:

```
memcpy(temp, our_string + rm[1].rm_so, rm[1].rm_eo - rm[1].rm_so);
```

Neither of your regular expressions have any groups; the second element of the `rm` array is not going to have anything useful in it. You need to use the *first* element, which has the offsets of the complete match:

```
memcpy(temp, our_string + rm[0].rm_so, rm[0].rm_eo - rm[0].rm_so);
```

You also have a memory leak because you don't have a `regfree(&re);` to free up memory allocated for the regular expression. Not a big deal in a simple demo program like this, but in something bigger or longer running or that does the matching in a loop, it'll become an issue.